# Swift: Align Default "command+/" With Code

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to Swift so this is probably a very basic fix.

When I create a comment I want the comment to properly align with my code. See my photo for an example.  [Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGDPQ.png)

Does anyone know how to change the default `command+/` behavior?

```
class DummyClass {
     let dummyVariable = "hello world"
     // Desired command+/ behavior

//    Default command+/ behavior
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to align your code:

1. The key combination to format all text on the open file:

[image]

2. Or try the following combination :

   - Select the block of code that you want indented.
   - Right-click (or, on Mac, Ctrl-click).
   - Structure → Re-indent.